# Exception Handling in Ruby - call begin if it goes to rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple exception handling block

```
begin
    <connect to network and make a request>
rescue
    <comes here if it didnt connect / whatever other error>
end
```

I want to modify it such that if it comes to rescue - it goes to begin again. Give 5 tries . If still not connecting - come out of the block

Comment: so why use begin resue block ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want the keyword `retry`. Couple that with a MAX_RETRIES. i.e. `if (MAX_RETRIES -= 1) > 0`
    retry

Comment: Reluctant +1: `MAX_RETRIES -= 1` is Bad (modifying a constant). @JulienPortalier has it right.

Comment: Fair point. I was just using it to illustrate the idea but you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Increment a counter and `retry` until that counter hits the value:

```rb
MAX_RETRIES = 5
retries = 0

begin
  do_something
rescue ex
  if retries += 1 <= MAX_RETRIES
    retry
  else
    raise ex
  end
end
```

You'll may want to retry on some Network related exceptions only, like timeout. Sometimes a not found or forbidden will always be, unless you poll until that changes.

Answer (score 1):

This should do :

```
 5.times do |i|
   begin
     1/0
   rescue
     puts 'Try #{i+1} failed ...'
     next
   end
   puts 'Try #{i+1} success.'
   break
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

write a method to connect to a network like this

```
def connect_to_server(retry_count)
  begin
   retry_count += 1
   <connect to network and make a request>
   rescue
     if(retry_count <= 5)
       connect_to_server(retry_count)
     end
  end
end
```

Call that method

```
connect_to_server(0)
```